# How do I change the size and specific height values of Unity generated terrain?

Tags: unity, terrain, procedural

I'm having problems with terrain scripting while trying to do a infinite-world with [Unity's terrain generation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/TerrainData.html).

How do I change the terrain height at specific points? And how do I set the amount of terrain generated?

Edit: What I'm having problem with is doing that **from a script**, from the editor is plain easy.

Comment: I was also looking for a tutorial to what http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/TerrainData.html means. You've edited my answer maybe a bit too much. Now If someone knows that, I won't get that answer.

Comment: I removed that because asking for tutorials is not the purpose of this site. Instead of asking for a tutorial, ask about the problems you think a tutorial will solve for you.

Comment: What have tried already? I created a terrain object and found it simple to change the size, and using the tools it's simple to change the height values. Maybe you can explain more about what you're having trouble with.

Comment: **"Using the tools"** I'm trying to do it from a script. I'm having trouble with understanding the obscure functions.

Comment: @Iridium616 Please provide the answer in the answers section.

Comment: I can't; Lack of reputation, I have to wait 8 hours.
"Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You can answer 2/2/2014 12:33:45 AM. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead."

Comment: Please wait until then, and answer the question; do not mark questions as "answered" in the title or edit the answer into the question. (I have *no idea* why that message suggests editing or commenting with answers, I can only surmise that it's a bug.)

Comment: I have [posted on MSO regarding the wording of the message](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218348/why-are-users-without-sufficient-reputation-prompted-to-place-answers-in-comment).

Comment: @JoshPetrie : Now It's telling me: You can accept your own answer tomorrow. Honestly, self-answering should be always okay.

Comment: I agree, but unfortunately it's a limitation of the software I cannot change (only somebody from SE could).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Nevermind. After an hour of trying I have found the method.

Well, it's actually a variable, and it's a Vector3 called "size", who could have guessed it?

I still can't believe I've missed it for that long.

For heights, still as obvious, "SetHeights method";

Comment: This doesn't address the changing specific height values portion of the question.